# Skip different number of rows in import

Tags: r

I'm importing a lot of datasets. All of them have some empty lines at the top (before header), however it's not always the same number of rows that I need to skip.

Right now I'm using:

```
 df2 <- read_delim("filename.xls", 
             "\t", escape_double = FALSE,
             guess_max=10000, 
             locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
             na = "empty", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 9)
```

But sometimes I only need to skip 3 lines fx.

Can I somehow set up a rule that when my column B (in Excel) contains one of the following words at the beginning of a sentence:

*Datastatistik*

*Overførte records*

*FI-CA*

*Oprettet*

Column A is always empty but I delete this in a code after the import.

This is an example of my data (I have hidden personal numbers):

[image: Example data]

My first variable header is called "*Bilagsnummer*" or "*Bilagsnr.*". 
I don't know if it's possible to set up a rule that says something like the first occurrence of this word is my header? Really I'm just brainstorming here, cause I have no idea how to automatise this data import.

**---EDIT---**

I looked at the post @Bram linked to, and it did solve some of my problem.

I changed some of it. 
This is the code I used:

```
 temp <- readLines("file.xls")
 skipline <- which(grepl("\tDatastatistik", temp) | 
                grepl("\tOverførte", temp) |
                grepl("FI-CA", temp) | 
                grepl("Oprettet", temp) |
                temp == "")
```

So the **skipline** interger that I made contains those lines that need to be skipped. These are correct using the grepl function (since the wording at the end of sentence changes from time to time).

Now, I still have a problem though. 
When I use **skip = skipline** in my **read.delim** It only works for the fist row.

I get the warning message:

```
  In if (skip > 0L) readLines(file, skip) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You want to change the number of skipped lines, but you also want to (always?) delete the first column? Not sure I completely understood what you asked for...

Comment: Yes I always delete the first column but I do that with brackets after the import, so that's fine. But I want to know how to skip lines when the number of lines to skip change from time to time. (Without just changing the number). 

I work with big datasets, so opening them first and checking the number of lines to skip is time consuming.

Comment: This post may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476685/skip-rows-in-read-table-within-for-loop
Let us know if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, some of it helped! Please see my edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

May have found a solution, but not the optimal one. Let's see.

Import your df with the empty lines:

```
df2 <- read_delim("filename.xls", 
         "\t", escape_double = FALSE,
         guess_max=10000, 
         locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
         na = "empty", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Find the number of empty rows at the beginning:

```
NonNAindex <- which(!is.na(df2[,2]))
lastEmpty  <- (min(NonNAindex)-1)
```

Re-import your document using that info:

```
df2 <- read_delim("filename.xls", 
         "\t", escape_double = FALSE,
         guess_max=10000, 
         locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
         na = "empty", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = lastEmpty)
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but it doesn't work. My data structure is very weird.. So when I import without skipping lines I only get one column (because there is only data in column B in row 2).

Comment: Oh ok! So in fact you are using the extension .xls but the data is not in that format...?

Comment: I have inserted an example of my excel data file in the question at the top. The format is .xls. Maybe a photo is better for understanding the problem :)